# CMake 3.14 or higher is required. You are running version 3.13.4

Tags: gnome, software-installation, compiling, docker, versions

When I set up a development environment using the following command:

`docker build -f Dockerfile.buster -t egot-dcs .`

I always get the error that "CMake 3.14 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.13.4"

However, when I check the `cmake` verison using `cmake --version`
it shows me the current version of `cmake` is **3.16**.

Does anyone know the problem with this one?

Comment: What OS & release are you using?    No currently supported release of Ubuntu (inc. *flavors*) use the `cmake` version you say you are running.   My guess is you should *release-upgrade* to a supported release of Ubuntu and the problem should be solved (*but note I don't know what release you are using, this is based on your version of `cmake` and the list of current versions available for supported releases*)  If you are indeed running 3.16.3 I would check $PATH etc.. but checking release details is still first step.